# Can openstack4j be used with Softlayer (not IBM Cloud) Swift Object Storage service?

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage, openstack4j

I have a running IBM Cloud Swift Object Storage service running with openstack4j. I need to move the containers to the similar service offered by IBM's Softlayer brand,

When I click in "View Credentials" in SoftLayer control panel I only get Authentication Endpoint, Username and API Key (Password) values. But openstack4j expects more values to allow a connection: Domain ID, Object Id, ... can I have OpenStack work with Softlayer (no Ibm Cloud) service?

It is important as for some reason, my Service Plan is not allowing me to create more instances of the Swift Object Storage service under IBM Cloud, I can only create them in Softlayer control.bluemix.net control panel.

thanks

Edit: This example is valid for IBM Cloud, not Softlayer service:

https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-sample-liberty

Answer (score 0):

Only the IBM Cloud Swift Object Storage service will support the OpenStack credentials.

You currently have data in the IBM Cloud Swift service and want to move it to the SoftLayer Swift service or you would like to create another instance of IBM Cloud Swift Object Storage service and move your data there?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. We have data but we don't really need to move. it. Just start using SoftLayer better than IBM Cloud service. As I see from the answer below, we need to use direct REST client to manage the service, as it won't support openstack4j. Is that correct? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Softlayer Object storage do not provide support with openstack4j, but maybe works for you the swift client you can see how to configure it here:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis